# QTextBrowser set link, can't make it clickable

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QTextBrowser, and setting it with link like this:

```
 QString url = 
    "http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html#source-prop";
 textBrowser->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
 textBrowser->setHTML(url);
```

or with:

```
 textBrowser->setSource(QUrl(url));
```

or even:

```
 QString u = "<a href=\""+url+"\">"+url+"</a>";
 textBrowser->setHTML(u);
```

but nothing happens.  If I add the setSource I don't even see the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used

```
textBrowser->setHTML(url);
```

but it isn't actually a valid HTML to create a link. You need to use `a href`. See the supported html subset here.

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html

Comment: i did this also :
QString u = "<a href=\""+url +"\">"+url+"</a>";
 ui->textBrowser->setHtml(url );
but still doesn't work

Comment: i just views how to set the HTML tags from the Designers view source